# when curl http://localhost:1337/parse response show curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 50497: Connection refused

Tags: windows, curl, parse-platform, connection

my question is: why I curl to another port curl in response show this massage that said Connection refused in port 50497[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT2if.png)